The number of real roots of a polynomial is approximately the log of its degree
I was reading this article on Wikipedia when I came across this claim:

Moreover, as the number of the real roots is, on the average, the logarithm of the degree, it is a waste...

Some experiments on Sage with an Excel regression line confirm this. Experimentally, for every $\epsilon > 0$, the expected number of real roots when sampling a random real polynomial with degree $n$ and coefficients in $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ is approximately $0.82 + 0.557 \log(n)$.
I could not find a proof of this fact in the article or in a brief Google search. What is the reason behind this phenomenon?

My interpretation of average was just expected value w.r.t. the uniform distribution over $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]^{n+1}$. Experimentally, this expectation seems to increase monotonically (so odd/even doesn't matter) when the coefficients are sampled from a symmetric domain, it would be more complicated over general domains.
